# Modifing settings in Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to get Django's manage.py to run with modified settings files.

I have three settings files

settings.py
preview.py
live.py

settings.py contains my base settings but on live & preview sites I point the ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] to live or preview which in turn load the base file and any settings specific to that environment.

This works fine, until I try to run migrations using manage.py

I updated the manage.py file to import settings.preview but now when I try to run syncdb or migrate I get this error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
>   You haven't set the DATABASE_ENGINE
>   setting yet.

My settings file has this in it though:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'mysql'
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't modify manage.py if you can help it. Instead pass it the `--settings` argument to choose an alternate settings module. Setting up a shell script or alias will make it easier to use this.